Is there any way to move cards from one component to other scheduler component in blazor C#?
I have a requirement to add tickets on the Scheduler board in Blazor C#. I want to slide cards from left to right on the scheduler board but I do not know if there is any way to achieve this.
I am using Telerik scheduler board and it is working fine. All I need is to move a card from somewhere outside the scheduler board to the scheduler board at a timeslot that I desire. Please find the below picture for your reference.

As per the above picture, I want to move the ticket from the left and assign it to a time on the right.
How do I achieve this in Blazor with or without Telerik?
Please help me with this.

Have you tried DropZone Component?

I know it but I can't assign a card directly to a scheduled time frame with it.
